# How to insert or delete query with jobs in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jobs, timer-jobs

I want to insert or update or delete in database automatically after cross a time e.g 8 hours.

Is it with jobs in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a litle more time to explain the problem, and what have you try it. Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Answer: **Yes**, it is.

Comment: I didnt downvote, But you get negative reputation, because your question isnt clear, read the link I provide and try to write a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a SQL Server job with TSQL code in it and schedule this job as appropriate.